# Is conducting a UX review while drunk a good idea?

Tags: heuristics, expert-review, evaluation

http://theuserisdrunk.com/

A system should be easy to use.

My question: will a drunk user be more error prone and likely to expose the flaws in a website more easily?

Comment: what a bizarre website...and this guy gets business? I...think I need to change my direction....

Comment: It depends on what the site is for. If it's a bar app - that may very well be a good idea. If its a financial dashboard - less so.

Comment: The real question is how to keep them awake during the review, or you have to consider it a flaw when the site losses the attention of a drunk person of course.

Comment: I've looked over this website in the past. It is an absolute farce and does nothing but damage the perception of UX. The reviews he conducts are an absolute joke and his rationale for being drunk for the review is purely false.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey No sense of humor. It started as a joke and people sent him money. Why shouldn't he have some fun with it? He also has a service where his friend's mom reviews the site. "Warning: This site not approved for grumpy UXers!"

Comment: This *is* an interesting question: We know that "being tired is not unlike being drunk" regarding attention, perception, response time etc. My rule of thumb is that you have at most 10% of the user's attention - because they have their own problems to solve. Plus, e.g. for social sites being drunk *is* a common use case.

Answer (score 10):

There's an article out there that I can't find now that advocates doing guerrilla testing in bars because it's a social environment where people are willing to help out for the price of a beer. I like the idea, though I've never done it.

You probably don't want to test with the heavily inebriated, but a beer and a half loosens people up and might make them into better subjects. Testing in a bar also provides some elements of real life, with interruptions and noises, that are missing in the lab.

Comment: ... this assuming your target audience is "Joe-everybody" on a consumer level.

Comment: Well, I believe that normal folk can find usability issues as well as a content-specific audience can. Most sites/apps I've tested haven't been too industry specific to test with Joe-everybodies. Even employee-facing UIs like corporate intranets, inventory-management systems, ordering systems, etc., can be tested by the general public. (I've seen too many cases where it's hard to test because we can't find users who match our audience exactly.)

Comment: True. I didn't intend to imply otherwise - though I sure didn't do a good job of that, as I re-read my comment. I think the idea is an interesting quirk, which could certainly garner useful information. The data would need to be handled very carefully though to avoid "insights" that ultimately don't fit with your final user base, or their work flows.

Answer (score 7):

**No.**

In my opinion thats compeltely wrong because drunk people arent less experienced,they are less logical in their actions and more prone to do **STUPID** mistakes,and not real mistakes.

If a drunk person trips over a ledge, is that ledge dangerous or the drunk person too drunk?

If anything i think **older** people are much more likely candidates to find out such flaws due to their possible *inexperience in technology*, if my grandma understands that pressing this shows me more information, i can be pretty assured my target audience will probably feel the same way about it even if they have never used any other websites beforehand.

edit: 
this does not mean we should put elderly people to try out our gaming forums,since they are not the target audience. im saying that in a specific group of people: for example "gamers" the best testing candidates are the ones with the least experience in the service,because they are less likely to get used to the common UX **FLAWS** that plagued them beforehand. never test your service with irrelevant people because you are adding another layer of falsehood to your results (ex: children not understanding certain industry standards on a finance website for buisness managers is **NOT** a UX flaw)

Comment: You said "I think older people are much more likely candidates to find out such flaws". Well it's funny you should say that... [The user is my mom](http://theuserismymom.com/)

Comment: i also specified the user has to be the target user. if im making a website about easy sawing tips for diy people, ill be sure to let his mom have a go at it.

Comment: Just because drunk people make "stupid mistakes" doesn't mean a sober person isn't capable of making the same mistake.  If drunk people keep tripping over your ledge, maybe you should put up a fence or something.

Comment: @Bobwise whats the point then,if sober people can make the mistakes and not understand something about your website,let **THEM** be your testing subjects.and not drunk people with an added variable of uncertainty

Answer (score 2):

Only if you expect your users to be drunk as well. This is a marketing gimmick being dressed up as UX. Avoid.

Comment: "One of the core tenets of UX is that you've got to design like "the user is drunk." ". No. No it isn't.

Comment: this is really horrible. people think UX is to enable people with a 2 digit IQ to use your website in an oversimplified insulting way. but dont realize what a great user experience makes of a difference for us in our daily life.

The **GOAL** of UX is to make something operateable in the most intuitive and easy way for the people that are going to **USE** your website. not drunk people. and not people that have nothing to do with the service.

Comment: downrep- I don't think its fair to say drunk people have a 2 digit IQ. Drunkeness is at the core not so much stupidity (though there is a little of that) but rather an altered state of mind, noticing things differently- some important things suddenly fade into nothing whilst minor bits stand out.
I think I'd agree with peter here. If you're going for the drunk market then it could be useful to put yourself in their shoes. Otherwise not really.

Comment: @theotherone i did not imply that,it was only an example of what UX is **NOT**

Answer (score 2):

Only if you value the feedback of an inebriated "full stack developer" who happens to be a "UX expert." Chances are good not many site visitors will fit that demographic.

Comment: The claim "UX expert" is highly suspicious.

Comment: Yes, as is the claim to be a "full stack developer." I was merely repeating what he thought of himself, tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 0):

Completely depends on the type of Application.

If your application is bound to cater to users who might be drunk, let's say for example - a Texting app that imitates your original texting app so that User does not send drunk texts to others, the app just stores the texts so that the user only thinks he sent them but in reality, it won't.

The idea is interesting! But, not anything more than a gimmick. Could work on Web sites for Bars, Pubs, etc just for the lulz.